# SMS backup apps, SMS Backup+, SMS Backup and Restore

Tags: sms, backup, automation

I've been using SMS Backup+ and when I restore not all my messages are restored, even though I can see them there in gmail. I've used SMS Backup and Restore before but it doesn't have a feature to automatically do it. Does anyone know how to fix SMS Backup+ or any other apps that work properly and have can automatically back up? I don't care if the backups are done to the SD card or online. One benifit of having it in gmail is that I can easily check to make sure it was done right. What do others think?

UPDATE: As of April 10 SMS Backup+ still doesn't restore all messages for some reason. I'm using an Xperia Z2.

Comment: SMS Backup and Restore does have the ability to automatically backup SMS's on a schedule and can email the backup to you.

Comment: @ZnewmaN where?

Comment: see my answer it has a picture by picture step to getting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring SMS Backup schedule in SMS Backup & Restore:

1. Open SMS Backup & Restore and click the Menu button in the upper right corner:

[image: SMS Backup & Restore]

2. Select Preferences:

[image: Preferences]

3. From the Preferences Menu, Select Schedule Settings:

[image: Select Schedule Settings option from Preferences Menu]

4. Configure schedule settings however you want:

[image: Schedule Settings Menu]

Comment: Ok thanks. Each backup is full so is it ok to select delete old backups because there included in each new backup?

Comment: I would think so or to select to keep a few.

Answer (score 2):

I only wanted to find a tool that could transfer my 3100+ SMS messages. So two weeks ago, I downloaded [AST Android SMS transfer](http://www.android-sms-transfer.com/) to transfer SMS from old phone to the new Galaxy S3, and it works well. But it's not a free program. I also use it to backup text messages to my PC in a `.csv` file, it's so convenient to check my messages.

Comment: That's a big issue I have is that it's not at all easy with SMS Backup and Restore or SMS Backup+ to check the integrity.

Answer (score 1):

None of the programs you mention will restore MMS messages. Perhaps those are the messages that are missing?

Comment: I think it was I needed to reboot my phone and give it time. But that's a very good point you made about MMS because I certainly do have those and didn't even notice they were missing. Do you know if Backup and Restore does incremental backups or full backups?

Answer (score 1):

To backup/restore both sms and mms for Android, I use a paid pc tool called Backuptrans Android SMS + MMS Transfer. You need to connect your Android to computer via usb or wifi then the software will save your sms and mms messages with attachment files on computer. Restoring MMS messages from computer to Android is also simple.